# Extract one single row per ID

Tags: sql, database

i have a problem to group some data from a table.
I want to get the full row with num = 1 only when names of row with num = 1 and num = 99 are different.

This is the example:

```
id |  name | num
001  frank   1
001  jonh    2
001  alfred  99
002  annie   1
002  maurice 99
003  mary    1
003  mary    99
```

I want to get this result:

```
id |  name | num
001  frank   1
002  annie   1
```

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: I apologize but if I wrote a help post I did not find a solution to my problem. Anyway, I tried to apply the suggestions that other users who in the past have written posts like mine, have received.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: I use MS SQL SERVER 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select '001' as id,  cast('frank' as nvarchar(10)) as name ,  1 as num
into #temp1

insert into #temp1(id,[name],num)
values
('001',  'jonh' ,   '2'),
('001',  'alfred' , '99'),
('002',  'annie' ,  '1'),
('002',  'maurice', '99'),
('003',  'mary'   , '1'),
('003',  'mary'   , '99')
select * from #temp1
where name not in (select name from #temp1 group by name having count(*)>1)
and num = 1
```

read the comment of Igor please